# Powershell AD cmdlets server logic

Tags: powershell, server, powershell-cmdlet

**I need to know the logic behind AD cmdlets for deciding which server will handle the request.**

The background is an temporary error message:

*"A connection to the directory on which to process the request was unavailable. This is likely a transient condition."*

I need to know which ADWS server is having the problem.

Note: i don't want to specify a server using the -Server property, i want to analyse the defect server

Answer (score 0):

Try same with `-verbose` Switch. It should show you the connected DC.